# Go to the next iteration of a for loop if .Find doesn't find anything in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, vba

```
For j = 1 To i
    If j = 1 Then FY = FY1
    If j = 2 Then FY = FY2
    If j = 3 Then FY = FY3
    If j = 4 Then FY = FY4
    If j = 5 Then FY = FY5
    If j = 6 Then FY = FY6
    If j = 7 Then FY = FY7
    If j = 8 Then FY = FY8
    If j = 9 Then FY = FY9
Sheets("Calcs").Select
Sheets("Calcs").Range("6:6").Find(FY).Select
With Worksheets(TabName).Range("C:C")
    Set FYFindj = .Range.Find(FY, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
    If FYFindj Is Nothing Then
        Next j
    End If
```

After the End If statement it does a bunch of stuff that works great.  I want the Macro to go to the Next iteration of j if it can't find a particular FY.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional `If` to test for the found range and move on if its not there. I refactored the code in your question for that, as well as cleaned up the setting of `FY`.

```
For j = 1 To i

    Select Case j
        Case 1 To 9: FY = "FY" & j
    End Select

    With Worksheets(TabName)

        If Not .Range("C:C").Find(FY, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then

            Set FYFindj = .Range("C:C").Find(FY, LookIn:=xlValues)
            'do stuff

        End If

    End With

Next
```

Comment: I believe that `FY1,FY2..` are variables, not values.  If that is the case the select case you have will not work.  I would change it to an array of values then then you can do `FY(j)`

Comment: good point @ScottCraner - I knew I was being deceived there somehow, but could not figure out what it was.

Comment: I am trying to use your second suggestion.  When I run it I am getting a Run-time error '450' "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" on the line that sets the FYFindj variable. My Code now looks like this:

Comment: @ML12 - sorry, I didn't have the `("C:C")` in there ... try now

Comment: @Scott, Thanks a lot.  I can't believe I missed that myself!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GOTO` statement

```
For j = 1 To i
    If j = 1 Then FY = FY1
    If j = 2 Then FY = FY2
    If j = 3 Then FY = FY3
    If j = 4 Then FY = FY4
    If j = 5 Then FY = FY5
    If j = 6 Then FY = FY6
    If j = 7 Then FY = FY7
    If j = 8 Then FY = FY8
    If j = 9 Then FY = FY9

    Sheets("Calcs").Select

    With Worksheets(TabName).Range("C:C")
        Set FYFindj = .Range.Find(FY, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    If FYFindj Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exit_Loop
    End If
Exit_Loop:

Next j
```

OR, use conditional logic:

```
For j = 1 To i
    If j = 1 Then FY = FY1
    If j = 2 Then FY = FY2
    If j = 3 Then FY = FY3
    If j = 4 Then FY = FY4
    If j = 5 Then FY = FY5
    If j = 6 Then FY = FY6
    If j = 7 Then FY = FY7
    If j = 8 Then FY = FY8
    If j = 9 Then FY = FY9

    Sheets("Calcs").Select

    With Worksheets(TabName).Range("C:C")
        Set FYFindj = .Range.Find(FY, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    If Not FYFindj Is Nothing Then
        '### DO a bunch of stuff that works great HERE

    Else:
        '### DON'T DO ANYTHING
    End If


Next j
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a follow on to my earlier comment.
    For j = 1 To i

```
    If j = 1 Then FY = FY1
    If j = 2 Then FY = FY2
    If j = 3 Then FY = FY3
    If j = 4 Then FY = FY4
    If j = 5 Then FY = FY5
    If j = 6 Then FY = FY6
    If j = 7 Then FY = FY7
    If j = 8 Then FY = FY8
    If j = 9 Then FY = FY9
Sheets("Calcs").Select

With Worksheets("Calcs").Range("6:6")
    Set FYFindj = .Range.Find(FY, LookIn:=xlValues) 'This is where I get the Run-Time Error
End With

If Not FYFindj Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Calcs").Range("6:6").Find(FY).Select
    addr = ActiveCell.Address
```

Comment: your answer is based on Scott Holtzman below, you need to credit him.